# Am I misunderstanding the usage of Export-Package in OSGI Bundles?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-3.6

I'm developing a plug-in that needs access to the class `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display`. This class is contained in `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.5.2.v3557f-RCP20100710-0200.jar`. However, the class is also exported by the manifest in `com.ibm.rcp.jfaceex_6.2.2.20100729-1241` as follows:

```
Export-Package: com.ibm.rcp.jface.action,com.ibm.rcp.jface.launcher,co
 m.ibm.rcp.jface.themes,com.ibm.rcp.jface.util,com.ibm.rcp.jface.viewe
 rs,com.ibm.rcp.jface.window,com.ibm.rcp.jface.window.effects,com.ibm.
 rcp.ui.widgets.api.jface,com.ibm.rcp.ui.widgets.api.swt
Require-Bundle: com.ibm.rcp.swtex,org.eclipse.swt,org.eclipse.core.run
 time,org.eclipse.jface,org.eclipse.ui
```

Now, `com.ibm.rcp.jfaceex` is *not* included as part of my JRE System Library. It is, however, a bundle that includes classes of its own, as well as the exported packages above.

I was led to beleve that all I needed to do in my own project was to include a reference to it in my own project's build path, but this does not appear to work. The compiler is unable to resolve import statements against the classes in the `org.eclipse.swt.widgets` package.

If I need those classes, what, exactly do I need to do to import them *correctly*, and with the least amount of work?

**Note** We are not using Maven or any third party build tools. This is mandated by management, and I cannot change it.

**UPDATE**

Per the suggestion of E-Riz, below, I added `org.eclipse.swt` to the Required Bundles section of the Dependencies tab of my plug-in. Then, I attempt to export the project as follows:

1. Right click project, select Export.
2. Select Plug-in Development -> Deployable plug-ins and fragments
3. Select All, then click Finish

Eclipse builds the project, then tells me there were errors. Examination of the log reveals the following error:

```
1. ERROR in E:\NotesDev\Plug-in\com.ibm.lotuslabs.ui\src\com\ibm\lotuslabs\ui\UI.java (at line 1)
    /**
    ^
The type org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

There are dozens of these throughtout my code; one for every reference to a class or method in the org.eclipse.swt namespace bundle. This, despite the fact that the bundle debugs just fine!

**UPDATE 2**

I've discovered that you *can*, in fact, put absolute paths into the `Bundle-Classpath` in `MANIFEST.MF`. Oddly, this made the compile-time errors vanish. I am not convinced at this point that this is the correct thing to do, since absolute paths are certainly not guaranteed to correspond to the end-user's configuration.

However, installing the plug-in into Notes (the target platform), is not working as intended.

Notes reports that the plug-in installed successfully, but the plugin (an addition to the toolbar) does not appear. I am assuming, at this point, that something with the classpaths still isn't right.

**UPDATE 3**

Per request, the `MANIFEST.MF` and `build.properties` files. Please note that absolute paths were added by Eclipse, through the Dependencies and Runtime tabs.

**`MANIFEST.MF`:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Context Plug-in
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.ibm.lotuslabs.context.service;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.2
Bundle-Vendor: IBM
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Bundle-Activator: com.ibm.lotuslabs.context.service.internal.ContextPlugin
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-ClassPath: context.jar,
 lib/activation-1.1.1.jar,
 lib/mail.jar,
 lib/SatuitCRM_XML_API2.jar,
 lib/commons-lang3-3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.jar,
 E:/NotesDev/Notes/framework/rcp/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.5.2.v3557f-RCP20100710-0200.jar
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.ui.views,
 org.eclipse.swt,
 com.ibm.rcp.swtex,
 com.ibm.rcp.jfaceex,
 com.satuit.core 
Export-Package: com.ibm.lotuslabs.context.service.document,
 com.ibm.lotuslabs.context.service.internal
Import-Package: org.eclipse.core.resources
```

**`build.properties`:**

```
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               context.jar,\
               lib/activation-1.1.1.jar,\
               lib/mail.jar,\
               lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar,\
               lib/SatuitCRM_XML_API2.jar,\
               plugin.xml,\
               E:/NotesDev/Notes/framework/rcp/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.5.2.v3557f-RCP20100710-0200.jar
jars.compile.order = context.jar
source.context.jar = src/
```

Comment: How about compiling result of your plug-ins inside Eclipse PDE? Are they successfully compiled by Eclipse?

Comment: No. The update above shows what happens after adding the fix. It's all very peculiar. Any modifications I make through Eclipse result in either being unable to debug the application due to a classpath error, or being able to debug it but being unable to export it due to a classpath error.

Comment: @Kane, I may have misunderstood your question. The code compiles just fine within PDE (I can clean and it builds just fine). I cannot, however, export it to a JAR without errors.

Comment: Not sure what's the problem. You can use latest Eclipse Juno to have a try.

Comment: @Kane, I tried doing so in Juno with fairly disastrous results, lol. Juno wouldn't even *launch* Notes (my plug-in host).

Comment: Definitely you incorrectly set your target platform to fail launch Notes. Juno just is IDE, it should not involve into runtime of your Notes running.

Comment: You should remove absolute reference of swt from your MANIFEST, build.properties and project build path.

Comment: @Kane, interestingly enough, those absolute paths were added by Eclipse. Further, when they were added, the runtime and compile-time errors went away. Upon inspection, the absolute paths appear on the Runtime tab in the Classpath section with the message that they specify paths that are not required to exist *at runtime.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure, but two things come to mind.

- Either remove the jar from your project classpath and add the com.ibm.rcp.jfaceex jar to your target platform (Preferences->PDE->Target platform and point to a directory containing the com.ibm.rcp.jfaceex jar)
- Or leave the reference and also add the jar to your bundle classpath (on the runtime tab of the MANIFEST)

It don't quite see how this would result in *this* error, but classpath problems can manifest themselves in weird ways in PDE.

Comment: The odd thing is that `com.ibm.rcp.jfaceex.jar` is already included in the target platform. I can see it when I go to *Preferences->Plug-in Development->Edit* and check the *Show Location Content* checkbox.

Comment: Also, if I add the jar to the bundle classpath, Eclipse Helios puts it in there with an absolute classpath, which (as I understand it) is undesirable, as it likely won't match the end-user's configuration.

Comment: Can you post your manifest.mf and build.properties files here or is is sensitive? There *must* be something there.

Comment: Sure, I can do that. I have another question for you. If a JAR file is already in the target platform, why would Eclipse generate errors telling me that it is not on the Build Path? I would assume that it doesn't need to be on the build path if it's in the target platform.

Comment: That *is* odd, I don't think you should have it on two locations. What is the exact error? I'd expect more a 'dependency can not be resolved' kind of error.

Answer (score 3):

Just because a bundle names a package in its `Export-Package` declaration does not necessarily mean that it *contains* the code for that package. A bundle can export packages from bundles that it depends on (although I think that's generally a bad idea in most cases).

For you, the solution is simple: in your `MANIFEST.MF` go to the Dependendencies tab and add `org.eclipse.swt` to the list of **Required Plug-ins**

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately, this produces errors when I attempt to export the bundle to a JAR file. Specifically, any types in org.eclipse.swt.widgets cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a look at the swt related bundles in eclipse juno:
org.eclipse.swt_3.100.0.v4233d.jar
org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.100.0.v4233d.jar

The widgets are in the second bundle which is a fragment to the first.

So you have to make sure both bundles are in the target platform. I am not sure if require bundle works in that case (it may work). You may try to instead import all packages you need.
Especially you need Import-Package on the package org.eclipse.swt.widgets.